# Python Loops-Adding

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-3.4, addition

I'm a beginner to Python and programming in general so I only understand a limited amount of terms...I'm having trouble adding in my while loop.  It adds everything except my first MoreExp.  I've been trying to figure it out for hours so I really have lost my patience.  If anyone could kindly explain why this won't add all of my MoreExp that would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Loop to determine expenses
while MoreExp != "0":
    MoreExp = input("Enter more expenses.  If no more, enter '0':  ")
    TotalExp += int(MoreExp)
if MoreExp is "0":
   AmountLeft = int(TotalIncome) - int(TotalExp)

TotalExp = int(TotalExp) + int(Expenses)
AmountLeft = int(TotalIncome) - int(TotalExp)

#Output total spent and amount leftover
print("Total amount spent from income: $", TotalExp)
print("Total amount left over after expenses: $", AmountLeft)
```

So I get this as my result:

```
What is your monthly income?  100
Enter your expenses:  5
Enter more expenses.  If no more, enter '0':  10
Enter more expenses.  If no more, enter '0':  6
Enter more expenses.  If no more, enter '0':  0
Total amount spent from income: $ 11
Total amount left over after expenses: $ 89
```

---

I just figured it out!!  I accidentally asked the user for MoreExp right before my loop started so it wasn't adding it to my TotalExp.  Thanks to those who helped though!!  Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be your entire code snippet. Where are the lines that ask for your monthly income and the first set of expenses? If I were to guess, I assume that you haven't set `TotalExp` to the value of the first set of expenses before entering the `while MoreExp` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I redid your whole code, but IT WORKS NOW!

```
Tot=input("Enter Income:")
NetInc=Tot
NetXpense=0
c = 0
while (c==0):
    Xpense=input("Enter your expenses:")
    NetXpense+=int(Xpense)
    if (int(Xpense)==0):
        c=1
NetInc = int(Tot)-NetXpense
print("Expenditure:",NetXpense)
print("Net Income:",NetInc)
```

*Try this and let me know :)*

Comment: I actually made a mistake prior to the start of my loop which I should've posted in my original post.  But I also tried your code and it worked!  Thank you :)

Comment: @AlyssaDettmer haha , glad I helped :) , next time , post the whole code ;)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
MoreExp = int(input("Enter more expenses.  If no more, enter '0':  "))
```